# Set an alpha layer to artificially reduce luminosity

Tags: android, user-interface

I'm new in android development and the first app I want to do for myself seems to use unusual means.

I want to set an alpha layer on the screen (like screen filter application).
I can set the alpha transparency of my application background but of course when I switch to another application there's no more filter.

A mean to do that could be by a service which remove focus on my main activity so I can interact with home or other application and when my action is over set focus again on my app with alpha background.

But honestly I don't know how to do that.
How do you think that screen filter application works and how can I reproduce this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it uses a service. Look more into services, and flags like "FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH".. There are actually quite a few discussion on this right [here](http://stackoverflow.com). It's very simple once you know what you're doing though with services and those flags though.